# Integration over function of Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I wish to calculate below 3 expectations of a typical Wiener process -

1. $E \left[ \int\limits_{0}^{T} tdW_t \right]$
2. $E \left[ \left( \int\limits_{0}^{T} tdW_t \right)^2 \right]$
3. $E \left[W_T \int\limits_{0}^{T} tdW_t \right]$

How should approach them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Question 1)** The Itô integral of a deterministic function is Gaussian, see [here](http://halweb.uc3m.es/esp/Personal/personas/bdauria/0910/Stoc_Proc_PhD/Notes/2010-04-13Tu_Notes.pdf) or [here](https://sites.duke.edu/probabilityworkbook/gaussian-ito-integrals/), i.e. $$\int_0^T f(u)\mathrm{d}W_u \sim N\left( 0,\int_0^T f(u)^2\mathrm{d}u\right).$$ The answer is thus zero. We of course need to require that $\int_0^T f(u)^2\mathrm{d}u<\infty$.
- **Question 2)** The simple version of [Itô's isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry) reads as $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^T X_u\mathrm{d}W_u\right)^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^TX_u^2\mathrm{d}u\right].$$ Setting $X_u=u$, the answer is to question two is thus $\int_0^T u^2\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{3}T^3$.
- **Question 3)** [Itô's isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry) generalises to $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^T X_u\mathrm{d}W_u\right)\left(\int_0^T Y_u\mathrm{d}W_u\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^TX_uY_u\mathrm{d}u\right].$$  Thus,

$$\mathbb{E}\left[W_T\int_0^T u\mathrm{d}W_u\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^T 1\mathrm{d}W_u\right)\left(\int_0^T u\mathrm{d}W_u\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T u\mathrm{d}u\right]=\frac{1}{2}T^2.$$

(Note: There is a typo in your question, the first Brownian motion should be $W_T$ and not $W_t$.)

Answer (score 3):

For this type of problem you need to use the [Ito isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry)

1. The first one is 0 due to symmetry of $W_t$ around 0
2. A really similar problem is solved with working in this post (I've copied the algebra below): http://www.quantopia.net/interview-questions-vii-integrated-brownian-motion/

[image: Integrated Brownian motion]

3. Looks like stochastic integration by parts might help here (also used in the post above)